# Amazon Policy Generator - Policy has Invalid resource

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-policy

After attempting to apply a bucket policy generated by [Amazon's policy generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html), I receive the error "*Policy has invalid resource*". Everything seems valid after using the [policy documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-policy-language-overview.html) to check my policy's validity. Here's my simple policy that is throwing the error.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1542588337862",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1542588336654",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dylan-landry-cms-portfolio/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Apologies for asking such a common question, but I'm stumped. I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: Your policy works fine for me (substituting my bucket name for yours). You should double-check that your bucket is called `dylan-landry-cms-portfolio`. When I run `aws s3 ls s3://dylan-landry-cms-portfolio`, it says that the Bucket does not exist.

Comment: I thought, surely, it could not be that. Turns out it was, I needed to append a "-site" to it. However, now I get an access denied error when I attempt to save it.

Comment: To stop the access denied error I had to set "Block new public bucket policies" to false under the Public access settings tab. Thanks for the help John, I will try to be more vigilant and double check what common errors my problem could be due to.